# Where dows Kuhn talk about intension of concepts?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kuhn

Kuhn talks about changement of concepts during scientific revolutions and says it affects both their intension and extension, and that within the new paradigm old terms, concepts, and experiments fall into new relationships one with the other.

In which book or essay does he claim that? Which is the quote?

Answer (score 4):

See SEP's entry [The Incommensurability of Scientific Theories : 2.3 Kuhn’s subsequent development of incommensurability : 2.3.1 Taxonomic incommensurability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incommensurability/#KuhSubDevInc) for discussion.

The relevant *loci* are from : Thomas Kuhn, [The Road since Structure : Philosophical Essays 1970-1993](https://books.google.it/books?id=sXufWLnPp94C&pg=PA33), Chicago UP, mainly from **Ch.2 : Commensurability, Comparability, Communicability**, page 33-on, where the term "*intension*" is used several times.

See also: **Ch.1 What Are Scientific Revolutions?**, page 29 :

> the distinctive character of revolutionary change in language is that it alters not only the criteria by which terms attach to nature [see: *intension*] but also, massively, the set of objects or situations to which those terms attach [see: *extension*].